# excel formula counting days after and before today

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, calculated-field

In Excel 2010 I have two columns one COLUMN  date is =TODAY() and the 2nd column has other dates some in the future some in the past how to have one formula to calculate the number of days from or to Today.  The output just needs to be a number

Comment: Have you tried subtracting one from another?

Comment: thanks for this but what about the days in the future, Iam  trying to see if i can get a formula to do it all in one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just subtract the past date from the `=TODAY()` column.

---

You also don't need the `=TODAY()` column to at all, just have the formula as:

`=TODAY()-A1` or whatever the cell is.

---

If you want the value to always be positive use:

`=ABS(TODAY()-A1)`

Comment: thanks for this but what about the days in the future, Iam  trying to see if i can get a formula to do it all in one

Comment: Well they'd show as negative days because they're in the future, unless you wanted both the day before and the day after to be 1? If you wanted to do that then wrap it in ABS()

Comment: Hi thanks for this what do you mean by wrap it in ABS() never heard of this before can you elaborate

Comment: ABS() will give you an Absolute value i.e. negative values become positive. Further reading [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ABS-function-3420200f-5628-4e8c-99da-c99d7c87713c).

Comment: so if i am using the formula =TODAY()-C3 where do i add in the ABS() formula

Comment: Same way as I've used it in the edit to my answer above.

Comment: If this sorts your issue feel free to follow the site guidance as per [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).